# What means this button state when my activity starts?

Tags: android, android-button

When my activity starts the button starts as below image, seems that it is selected.

[button seems to be selected http://kodeinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/post4_1.jpg](http://kodeinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/post4_1.jpg)

Button seems to be selected but I don't select it neither on activity nor layout.

I had checked and this is not related to focus. I tried starting the activity with `requestFocus()` on a button and does not have the same behavior.

Does anyone knows what is that? What is this state for the button? I don't want this behavior in my app, but I'm not being able to understand the issue in my code because I don't know what this state is.

Comment: Probably it has something to with the device... possibly trackball? http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2008/12/touch-mode.html

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, the xml have only two buttons and class have nothing special, only findViewByID and setText on buttons.

I had in other class of my app a hide soft keyboard, can it has any relation?
I checked that if I remove the line that hides the keyboard this behavior of button selected does not happens...
But I still don't know what does mean a "selected" button or what does really means this button highlighted in blue.

Comment: @AndrewT., no this is not tackball I'm using a Nexus 4.

Comment: Post your code. Include res files and drawables (if you have them). If it isn't based on focus, it is based on "enabled" or "pressed" - looks like pressed but could be a button is "disabled"

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, I had created another question that is better explained than this one, since I was able to filter better the real issue. Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050699/using-keyboard-with-statealwaysvisible-after-touch-any-letter-its-select-the

Can anyone help me marking this question as duplicated or something, making reference to the below question link? Thanks!