# Using keyboard with stateAlwaysVisible, after touch any letter its "select" the button, why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have only one button in my layout and the activity has nothing. On Manifest it has the android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" for the activity, to always show the keyboard.

The problem is that when touch any key on keyboard the only one button is kind selected. Like "highlighted" the entire button in blue.

But I don't want this behavior, how can I avoid it?

Sorry I can not add images because of my reputation...

Below are my codes:

Manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivityTest"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
</activity>
```

Activity:

```
    public class MainActivityTest extends Activity {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_test);
       }
    }
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to your LinearLayout can avoid this behavior:

```
  android:focusable="true"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

I have tried and it works well.

Comment: ok, that approach works in this case, thanks for your help! But I had resumed my problem because it has much more code involved. Do you know any way of avoid this behavior after click on keyboard?

For example, if I have an AlertDialog with posite/negative button in this activity if it launchs after a keyboard press then the positive/negative button will be selected.
Also if pressed the back button and moves to another activity (even from other app) that don't has the `focusable=true` it will select any view on that. Did you get my point? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: @JonasOliveira I'm not very clear about this problem, I think it's a little complex, so you'd better post another question and post your code and layout involved in this problem.

Comment: I had created another question with more information, please could you take a look and share?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071788/using-keyboard-with-statealwaysvisible-after-touch-any-letter-the-showed-alertd