# Using keyboard with stateAlwaysVisible, after touch any letter the showed AlertDialog opens selected, why?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog

I have only one button in my layout. 
The activity after count of 10 (five keyboard touchs) shows an `AlertDialog`.
On Manifest the activity has the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"`, to always show the keyboard.

The problem is that after touch any key on keyboard the only one button is kind selected. Like "highlighted" the entire button in blue.

I could use below code on layout to solve the button problem:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

But for the `AlertDialog`, it will opens selected.

Also happens with the `AlertDialog`, it opens with one of the buttons selected.

But I don't want this behavior, how can I avoid it?

Below are my codes:

Manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivityTest"
   android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible">
</activity>
```

Activity:

```
    public class MainActivityTest extends Activity {

       static int count = 0;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_test);
       }

        @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

    count += 1;
    Log.d("Count: ", "Count: " + count);
    if(count >= 10){
        count = 0;

        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Title");
        builder.setMessage("Message");
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
    }
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_testButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a View Focus problem. You can solve it with the method below.

Change your code:

```
  AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
```

To:

```
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            ViewParent parent = alert.getButton(
                    AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getParent();
            if (parent instanceof ViewGroup) {
                ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) parent;
                vg.setFocusable(true);
                vg.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                vg.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Comment: Thank you Leog, I will try that at home.
One more question: Let's remove the AlertDialog in this example.
And we create a previous activity with a Button that will open the `MainActivityTest` activity, so after reach the count (by keyboard keys touchs), hide the keyboard and then you press back button (`onBackPressed()`). Then you will be back to first activity and the button on it will be selected as the same of AlertDialog.
The same problem happens if you have any other application opened on android stack, and press back button going to this another app, so a button/listItem will be selected